# Local variable 'cliente' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

Quiero proteger la vista de una plantilla, como tengo varios tipos de usuarios extendidos con modelo `User` de Django, me cuesta trabajo. Ya lo he intentado de muchas formas pero sin éxito, esta es una y me da error.

Esta es la vista:

```
def ViajesCliente(request, id_cliente):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        usuario = request.user.id

        try:
            cliente = Cliente.objects.get(usuario_id = usuario)
            bandera = True
        except cliente.DoesNotExist:
            bandera = False

        if bandera == True:
            if cliente.id == id_cliente:
                viajes = Viaje.objects.filter(cliente_id = id_cliente)
                viajes_p = Viaje.objects.filter(cliente_id = id_cliente, estado = 'P')
                viajes_c = Viaje.objects.filter(cliente_id = id_cliente, estado = 'C')
                viajes_r = Viaje.objects.filter(cliente_id = id_cliente, estado = 'R')
                contexto = {
                'viajes': viajes,
                'viajes_p': viajes_p,
                'viajes_c': viajes_c,
                'viajes_r': viajes_r,
                }
                return render(request, 'cliente/servicio.html', contexto)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home:index'))
```

Estos son los modelos:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import date, datetime
# Create your models here.


class Cliente(models.Model):
 usuario = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
 cedula = models.CharField(max_length = 10, unique = True)
 telefono = models.CharField(max_length = 12)
 rol = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

class BitacoraCliente(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete = 'cascade', default = None)
 descripcion = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
 fecha = models.DateField(default = datetime.today)
```

Comment: posdata: ya intente declarar la variable cliente antes asi:
    cliente = ''  
y tambien:
    cliente = None
 y no funcionó

Comment: Cambia `except cliente.DoesNotExist:` a `except Cliente.DoesNotExist:`

Answer (score 1):

Como menciona @eyllanesc, el problema es que [`DoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.DoesNotExist)  es una excepción del modelo, por lo tanto lo correcto sería:

```
try:
    cliente = Cliente.objects.get(usuario_id = usuario)
    bandera = True
except Cliente.DoesNotExist:
    bandera = False
```

Ya que `cliente` es la variable que estás tratando de asignar, de ahí el error.

Otra forma de hacerlo es usar [`ObjectDoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/exceptions/#objectdoesnotexist) que es la clase base para capturar excepciones cuando el objeto no existe en la base de datos:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

# ...

try:
    cliente = Cliente.objects.get(usuario_id = usuario)
    bandera = True
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    bandera = False
```

Esta excepción capturará el error para **cualquier modelo**.

Answer (score 0):

Hay algunas observaciones que te las pondre a modo de comentario

```
def ViajesCliente(request, id_cliente):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        usuario = request.user # aqui es mejor coger el objecto completo django se encarga de la comparacion 

        try:
            # he quitado el "_id" para igualar directamente con el objeto, 
            # pero si quisieras igualarlo con el id de igual manera lo correcto 
            # seria poner dos guiones bajos asi : "usuario__id=usuario.id" para 
            # acceder a un atributo (id o nombre, etc) de un atributo objeto (usuario) 
            # desde un objeto modelo (Cliente) se usa el doble guion bajo
            cliente = Cliente.objects.get(usuario = usuario) 
            # esto lo pongo aqui para quitarnos un if y una variable
            if cliente.id == id_cliente:
                viajes = Viaje.objects.filter(cliente_id = id_cliente)
                viajes_p = Viaje.objects.filter(cliente_id = id_cliente, estado = 'P')
                viajes_c = Viaje.objects.filter(cliente_id = id_cliente, estado = 'C')
                viajes_r = Viaje.objects.filter(cliente_id = id_cliente, estado = 'R')
                contexto = {
                'viajes': viajes,
                'viajes_p': viajes_p,
                'viajes_c': viajes_c,
                'viajes_r': viajes_r,
                }
                return render(request, 'cliente/servicio.html', contexto)
        except Cliente.DoesNotExist: # la excepcion la tienes que hacer apartir del modelo y no de tu variable
            pass         
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home:index'))
```